# Calculate the 2-norm of a matrix in python without NumPy

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the 2-norm of a given matrix without using NumPy.

```
A = ([[1, 2, 3, 4], 
    [5, 6, 100, 8],
    [9, 200, 11, 12]])

def norm2(A):
    f = 0

    for i in A:
        for j in range(0,len(A[0]))
          f = f + sum((abs(A[i, j]))^2)
    return(sqrt(f))

print(norm2(A))
```

But I can't understand why it is not workings

Comment: If you have a problem with a particular answer, please discuss/resolve that under that answer. Don't make it part of the question.

Comment: As a side note, this is not what the 2-norm of a matrix [really is](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code that are causing it to not work as expected. Here are some modifications you can make to fix them:

1. In the inner for loop, you are trying to access elements of the matrix A using indices i and j. However, i is a row of A, not an index, so you should just use i instead of A[i]. Also, you should use j to access the elements of A[i] instead of using A[i, j] which is not valid syntax in Python. Instead, use A[i][j].
2. You are using the ^ operator to calculate the square of each element of the matrix. However, in Python, ^ is the bitwise XOR operator, not the exponentiation operator. To calculate the square of a number, you can use the ** operator.
3. You are missing a colon (:) at the end of the range function call in the inner loop. Without the colon, Python will raise a syntax error.

Here is the modified code:
from math import sqrt

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
    [5, 6, 100, 8],
    [9, 200, 11, 12]]

def norm2(A):
    f = 0

    for i in A:
        for j in range(0, len(A[0])):
            f = f + abs(A[i][j])**2

    return sqrt(f)

print(norm2(A))
```

With these modifications, your code should now calculate the 2-norm of the given matrix correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But i run into sum errors. Specifically ,see update

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted this to look like Python:

```
total = sum(value ** 2 for row in A for value in row)
return sqrt(total)
```

Comment: Or just `return hypot(*map(hypot, *A))`.

Comment: @KellyBundy   Maybe.  But that does a lot of unnecessary square roots.  I also think any piece of code with two different '*' in the argument list is harder to understand. YMMV.